# Сочетание слов "куда важнее" выделяется запятыми?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

Куда важнее, ты поранился из-за меня... - тут нужна запятая после "куда важнее"? И является ли оно вообще вводным словом?

Comment: Не является вводным оно, на мой взгляд, и не хватает "что".

Comment: Артем, если подчинительного союза "не хватает", то тогда это БСП (бессоюзное сложное предложение).

Comment: Тогда, получается, запятая должна стоять?

Comment: В БСП возможна постановка разных знаков (тире, двоеточие, запятая). Выбор нужно обосновать.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо!

Comment: Я чуть позже напишу ответ, если не будет других ответов.

Comment: Марианна, на сайте принято благодарить участников за полезные вопросы и ответы стрелочкой (треугольником) вверх, а также принимать один из ответов галочкой как наиболее понравившийся и решивший проблему.

Answer (score 1):

1. Стандартная запись предложения выглядит так: ***Куда важнее, что ты поранился из-за меня...***
   Сравнить: Куда важнее, что он думает на самом деле. [Александра Маринина. Последний рассвет (2013)]  Но это книжная, а не разговорная речь.
2. Часто встречаются **такие варианты**: Куда важнее **другое** ― подданные сами признавали за ними право контролировать детали своей частной жизни... Впрочем, куда важнее **другое**: структура продаж российского авиапрома за последние два года кардинально изменилась. Это бессоюзные сложные предложения со значением изъяснения (БСП), можно поставить двоеточие или тире.
3. Если не использовать слово "другое", мы тоже имеем БСП с изъяснительным значением, только первое предложение **безличное**. Здесь хорошо подходит тире, обозначающее паузу: ***Куда важнее – ты поранился из-за меня..**.*
4. Запятая допускается при отсутствии интонационного предупреждения (паузы): ***Куда важнее, ты поранился из-за меня..***.
5. **И по поводу вводного слова.** Действительно, сочетание "куда важнее" при обособлении запятой в какой-то мере сходно с вводными словами. Это позиция в начале слова, семантика, выражающая субъективную оценку говорящего. Но по своей структуре его вряд ли можно отнести к разряду вводных слов. Сравнить: *Главное – ты поранился из-за меня...* Вот это уже вводное слово, и в начале предложения оно обычно обособляется тире.

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо!